# Which data type should I choose for audio and video files in a LocalDB at WPF Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql, wpf, visual-studio-2010, localdb

I am making a WPF application using Visual Basic and a Local database. The problem is: When I create tables in my local DB, I need a data type to save an audio or video file. I want to insert this file into my local DB, but I don't know what data type to choose for an audio or video file. The possible options are: binary and varbinary. There's no other option. Or maybe I should save the file address?

Comment: Could you add a little more detail. Perhaps the size of the files and basically what the database is for?

Comment: Hi, @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen . Well, I don't know what would be the size of the files, that's what I want to know what kind of data type choose. And the database are SQL (I guess, because this is at Visual Studio). And thank you for fix my grammatical errors in my english.

Answer (score 0):

Use varbinary(MAX) - stores 2 GB. But better option depending on your requirements is to use file system

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on what the differences might be between the file formats?

Comment: Varbinary it seems to be the best option, but in the cell to indicate the extension, "MAX" is not an option, just integer numbers.